Multiple key value pairs for select and onchange
Currently I have a select with a list set in the model and an onchange to display the information according to that value. An update has been requested to have another section of the Model added. I have tried this a few different ways and cannot figure out how to do this.
The code as it currently stands in the View
<div style="display:grid;grid-template-columns:25% 35%;">
    <label>Select a plan: </label>
    <select class="form-control inert" id="selPlan" onchange="chkForSaveBeforeChangeIP(this.value);" asp-for="SelectedPlanID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.IpDictionary, "Key", "Value"))">a
    </select>
</div>

The code as it currently stands in the controller:
Dictionary<int, string> ipDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

PReportEntryViewModel prVM = new()
                             { 
                                 IepID = iepID, 
                                 CatTypeID = iep.CatTypeID, 
                                 SelPlanID = selInstrPlan.IepPlanID, 
                                 StudentID = iep.StudentID 
                             };

if (selInstrPlan!= null)
{
    prVM.SelPlanID = selInstrPlan.IepPlanID;

    foreach (var iip in iipList)
    {
        ipDict.Add(iip.IepPlanID, iip.EdNeedType.EdNeedTypeName);
    }

    prVM.IpDictionary = ipDict;
}

For example the EdNeedType name may be have a drop down with an option that states Academic and based off of that, data will show below, but for the Academic option, there is a content area named Math and the user is wanting the drop down to show "Academic Math" but only the Academic is what the function is searching for so having both will cause it not to change the information
I have tried adding in the controller multiple ways. One was to have a second dictionary that appended content area
caDict.Add(iip.IepPlanID, iip.EdNeetType.EdNeedTypeName + ' ' + iip.ContentArea)

prVM.caDictionary = caDict

And then using that in the View, but the onchange is looking for just the EdNeedTypeName in order to populate the information below for the selected item. I am not sure how to show bot EdNeedTypeName and ContentArea but only look at EdNeedTypeName for the on change population of the data below
